# Github Actions with Docker - Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)?

Tags: docker, github-actions

While doing project, I'm having trouble creating own Github Actions using Dockerized way. During the action run process, I receive the error message `Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)`. But I build it, `node_modules` is created in container. So it should be there. I checked other issues on stack but they seems to be only locally, nothing Github Action related.

Here's an illustration of my Github Actions workflow:

action.yml (in `User/my-action@main`)

```yaml
name: 'Reusable Action'
description: 'Independent Reusable Action'

inputs:
  github-token:
    description: 'Github token'
    required: true

outputs:
  some_output:
    description: 'Some output'

runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
```

and here Dockerfile (in `User/my-action@main`)

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH=/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh-client python3 make g++

# copy project
COPY . .

# Check yarn, should be 3.5.0 (it shows up as 3.5.0)
RUN cat /usr/src/app/.yarnrc.yml
RUN printf "Project yarn version: "; yarn --version

# Install yarn dependencies
RUN yarn install

# build
RUN yarn build
RUN echo "Successfully built"

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

here's how I call for it in workflow (in `User/other-repo`)

```yaml
name: My reusable action in other repo
description: It's reusable

inputs:
  secret_token:
    required: true
    description: Secret to use for authentication

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - name: Do this
      id: my-id
      uses: User/my-action@main
      with:
        github-token: ${{ inputs.secret_token }}

    - name: Overwrite PR body
      id: overwrite_pr_body
      uses: AsasInnab/pr-body-action@v1
      with:
        body: ${{ steps.my-id.outputs.some_output }}
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ inputs.secret_token }}
```

When running it locally (`docker build -t my-test-image .`) it pass through... but when running in GitHub Actions it fails with above error code.

What I've tried so far besides what we have above:

- Updated project to yarn berry
- Removed due to [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/625) issue the yarn.lock
- Specified `usr/src/app` workdir

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a repo. Thanks!

Comment: sure I'll tinker something in free time, I'll let you know, thanks for pointing this out, I forgot that it can help

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation, I found that the issue was with the way I was running the `yarn start` command. I had originally included it in the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directive in the `Dockerfile`.

However, I found that by moving the `yarn start` command to a separate script and then calling that script from the "ENTRYPOINT" directive, the container started up properly within Github Action.

Final look:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH=/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh-client python3 make g++

# copy entrypoint
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# Check yarn, should be 3.5.0 (it shows up as 3.5.0)
RUN cat /usr/src/app/.yarnrc.yml
RUN printf "Project yarn version: "; yarn --version

# Install yarn dependencies
RUN yarn install

# build
RUN yarn build
RUN echo "Successfully built"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And script `/entrypoint.sh` script

```bash
#!/bin/sh -l

echo "Running action"
cd /usr/src/app && yarn start
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Edited to add;

Per the issue being solved by changing the entry point, it would seem that the [`node:16-alpine` entrypoint](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/16/alpine3.16/docker-entrypoint.sh) was trying to run yarn *through* node, rather than shell.

Although you've got it working now, it's good to keep in mind that your entrypoint won't always be `sh`. Although starting with the entrypoint set to a script is a good pattern, a similar fix to the original `CMD` would be `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]`.

##### Original

The `docker build` may "complete" fine (read: without error) locally, but `yarn install` can fail silently, i.e. it can fail to install properly but exit 0 -- so your build can "succeed" without it *actually being successful*. At a minimum, try `docker run --rm -it my-test-image sh` to jump into a shell in the finished build and confirm that it *actually* built correctly.

I suspect that there is a difference in the version of yarn installed in the base image and the version your configuration may be targetting, so you might need to update yarn before installing, if it failed to install properly.

*As a side note*, you don't need to use another repository (`User/other-repo`) to invoke it, you can test / call the action from the repo that contains it, `uses: ./` will use an `action.y[a]ml` in `./` of your repository. [*For example*](https://github.com/Skenvy/julia-release/blob/d2eb655e0245b102ac84d1169da8a1c097e6d110/.github/workflows/main.yaml#L40-L50). It's good practice to test the action with a workflow that `uses:` it, that can be a CI workflow on the repository that will publish the action.

Comment: By paragraphs
1. yes, it builds correctly, no yarn-error.log, just my dist/main with index.js
2. this was our main concern, that's why the project itself was moved to yarn berry 3.5.0 later (this is in the "what I tried so far" section)
3. yes, I'm aware that I can use it from the same repository as workflow, but we need this project to be maintained as a separate repo and only used elsewhere with only action, without touching/downloading the code directly